# Hiding specific items in Combo box temporarily

Tags: vb.net

I am a beginner in .NET programming. Trying to do coding with comboboxes. I have two combo boxes with me. The items in both combo-boxes are same. The names of cities. What i am looking for is, when a user selects one city in first combobox, the same city should not be visible in second combo box. I tried 'Remove' and 'RemoveAt' but the problem is, i dont want to change collection or indices of items in the collection. In addition to this, if user selects another city later, the first one should appear again in the list and the later one should get vanished. 
Please help me on this.. Thank you in advance.

Comment: based on your target deployment platform (web or desktop), answer will very. Please provide more details

Comment: target deployment platform is desktop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just saw your question, and the answer will get pretty long, because there is no way of simply making a single item not appear to the user without either removing it.  But I can propose a different solution to your question.

I am going off the following assumptions:

1. The collection of cities is predetermined by you
2. That the user selects one city, and a different city in the second combo box

So, I will try to do this as concisely as possible.

First Step:  Make two new settings of type 'String Collection' and add the list of cities to both of them

Second Step:  Make two new string variables at the top of your class (you want them to be accessible ball all controls on the form)

```
       Private Sub ComboBox1_Leave(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Leave
            If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then 
                 myStringOne = vbNullString ' Nothing is chosen
            Else
                 myStringOne = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString 'One of the two variables as described in the second step
            End If
            If Not myStringOne = vbNullString Then
                 ComboBox2.Items.Remove(myStringOne) ' Remove it just for now
            End If
        End Sub

       Private Sub ComboBox1_Enter(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Enter 
            If myStringTwo = vbNullString Then
                 ComboBox1.Clear ' Clear list
                 For Each city in My.Settings.CitiesListOne
                      ComboBox1.Items.Add(city)
                  Next 
            Else  'User selected a city in ComboBox2
                 ComboBox1.Remove(myStringTwo)
            End If
       End Sub

       Private Sub ComboBox2_Leave(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Leave
            If ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1 Then ' Nothing is chosen
                 myStringOne = vbNullString
            Else 
                 myStringTwo = ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString 'One of the two variables as described in the second step
            If Not myStringTwo = vbNullString Then
                 ComboBox1.Items.Remove(myStringTwo) ' Remove it just for now
            End If
       End Sub

       Private Sub ComboBox2_Enter(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Enter 
            If myStringOne = vbNullString Then
                 ComboBox2.Clear ' Clear list
                 For Each city in My.Settings.CitiesListTwo
                      ComboBox2.Items.Add(city)
                 Next
            Else  'User selected a city in ComboBox1
                 ComboBox2.Remove(myStringOne)
            End If
        End Sub
```

As you stated that you are new to VB.NET, I tried not to do anything too complicated that you could not debug on your own.  There are more concise and effective ways to do what you want, but without seeing your code, just felt like keeping it simple.  Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the `Enabled` condition to False on your `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged 
    Dim x as integer
    x = ComboBox1.SelectedValue

    For i as integer = 1 to ComboBox2.Items.Count -1
       ComboBox2.Items(i).Enabled = True
    Next

    ComboBox2.Items(x).Enabled = False 

   End Sub
```

You need to have the `autopostback` feature enabled.

Hope this helps.